# Can I make http requests directly to the janusGraph server?

Tags: distributed-system, janusgraph

Looking for an example of how to query the janusGraph server via HTTP. I need this option because I want to measure the speed of the janusGraph via Gatling. I didn't find documentation on how to set up the server that I can call via HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to this path: "**janusgraph-hadoop2/conf/gremlin-server**" and change **row** in "**gremlin-server.yaml**" from "c**hannelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer**" to "**channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.HttpChannelizer**". After that you need run gremlin server and can call end-point: "localhost:8182"